# rosrun map_server map_saver keeps on waiting does not generate map

Tags: ros, rosbag, map-saver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello, i am Build a Map Using Logged Data. I am following the procedure as explained in the ROS Tutorial [click to go](http://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData).

Here are the steps i am following:-

```
1. $ roscore
2. $ rosparam set use_sim_time true
3. $ rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=base_scan
4. $ rosbag play --clock mylaserdata.bag
```

**everything goes fine till here, but at the 5th step while executing following command...**

```
5. $ rosrun map_server map_saver
```

**This displays following message:-**

```
[INFO] [1413492118,722337006]: Waiting for the map
```

**and then map_server keeps on waiting but neither it stops nor save the map**, i am wondering why this is happening i can't figure out the problem since there are not any error, **the size of my bag file is 5MB**.

please help, thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195176/rosrun-map_server-map_saver-keeps-on-waiting-does-not-generate-map./) by [sumant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20291/sumant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2014-10-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-16**:
If you watch the map building progress in rviz, do you see a map being built?

**Comment by [sumant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20291/sumant/) on 2014-10-18**:
i am new to ros, & unable to open my robot model in rviz (it gives no transformation issue within status).
I am using P3AT (spawned in USARSim).
do i need to have urdf file.

**Comment by [sumant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20291/sumant/) on 2014-10-18**:
please help how to open map in rviz. (step by step procedure if possible)

**Comment by [sumant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20291/sumant/) on 2014-10-22**:
finally working by using this,

```
$ roscore  
$ roslaunch usarsim_inf usarsim.launch  
$ rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=lms200 
$ rosrun teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard.py
$ rosrun map_server map_saver
$ eog ./map.pgm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

finally working by using this,

$ roscore  
$ roslaunch usarsim_inf usarsim.launch
$ rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=lms200 
$ rosrun teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard.py
$ rosrun map_server map_saver
$ eog ./map.pgm

---

Originally posted by [sumant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20291/sumant/) with karma: 77 on 2014-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sumant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20291/sumant/) on 2014-11-17**:
@Aarif, Thank you.

**Comment by [maha](https://answers.ros.org/users/21965/maha/) on 2015-03-24**:
hello, can u please tell what are those launch files because i have the same problem

**Comment by [sumant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20291/sumant/) on 2015-04-28**:
we are updating most of the imformation on **https://tucrlab.wordpress.com/** . /by the way what do you want to know about above launch files.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like map is not published. Start rviz to view the map generated.

```
rosrun rviz rviz 
Add a display with a map, set to the topic /map
```

ps: in case you are using your own bag file, first try with test bag file mentioned in link you are following.

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-10-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1